# Using Ant to build multiple jars

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have multiple Java eclipse projects. Each of them has "jardesc" file for building jar. It's nice - double click -> finish and jar file is made. But when i have to export several jars it's a pain - i have to repeat procedure several times.
Please tell me, can i use Ant script to run several "jardesc" files at once (and get several jars according to each jardesc file)? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `subant` task in ant. You can create ant-file which would call other files to.

```
    <subant target="create_jar1">
        <fileset dir="." includes="jar2.xml"/>
    </subant>
    <subant target="create_jar2">
        <fileset dir="." includes="jar1.xml"/>
    </subant>
```

Comment: Is this suposed a call to another ant thask that build the jar or is this a call to jardesc. Plz be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the jar target to make the jars for you:

```
    <jar destfile='destination.jar' basedir='source\dir\' />
```

so your build.xml would look a little like this:

```
    <project default="makejars">
        <target name="makejars">
            <jar destfile="app1.jar" basedir="app1\src\" />
            <jar destfile="app2.jar" basedir="app2\src\" />
            <jar destfile="app3.jar" basedir="app3\src\" /> 
        </target>
    </project>
```

then just run ant in the same directory as build.xml, and the jars should be made.

Answer (score -2):

You can use some loops to create ant parameters however **there is no way to loop to create multiple jars** (even with ant-commons extension), a copy & paste is the only viable solution **unless you want to write an ant plugin** (which doesn't really take that much 2 hours reading docs + write simple plugin)

Comment: ant-contrib has `for` and `foreach` tasks