# Calling jardesc in Ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have a collection of projects whose build process is described by a .jardesc each. Sometimes I dont want to build single projects but all of them at once. Is it possible to make an ant build which calls/executes a list of jardescs?

In this question [using ant to build multiple jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608566/using-ant-to-build-multiple-jars) the same thing is asked but the answer marked as correct only works for building multilple jars using multiple ant builds, not the jardescs. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It's possible but would require ANT to launch eclipse to perform the build. Not very efficient.

Comment: I'm interesting how to call multiple .jardesc too